# Angular2+ - Cannot find module when passed as variable - testing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, require

In my test I am requiring a .json file with data that I will check against. However, I cannot seem to pass the string of where to find it into the require...

**Working code**

```
const data = require('../../../assets/data.json');
```

**Does not work**

```
const jsonUrl = '../../../assets/data.json';
const data = require(jsonUrl);
```

I am wanting to use the variable `jsonUrl` as this url string is to be used a few times within the test itself. I just don't understand why it cannot find it?

---

### **Amendment to question:**

Since mocking is the way to go on this, and I am unsure of exactly how to do this... I am amending  the question to help with this.

From what I am thinking with testing, I assume that I need to read in the data I am actually using and then test with that. If I am wrong then please correct me.

Here is what I am testing...

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "one",
    "id": 1,
  },
  ...
  // This format is used for approx 20 entries
]
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
   loadData().subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
    };
}

loadData() {
   const statusUrl = '../../../assets/data.json';
   return this.httpClient.get(statusUrl);
}
```

**test.ts** Receiving cannot find module because of require issue stated above.

```
it('should load status data from local json', fakeAsync(() => {
    const jsonUrl = '../../../assets/status.json';
    const data = require(jsonUrl);
    const request = httpMock.expectOne(jsonUrl);
    request.flush(data);
    expect(component.status).toEqual(data);
  }));
```

Comment: Well for starters, `require` is not advised in Typescript. [Try that](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79) to import your data, and otherwise, you can still mock it. Besides, why would you use JSON when you can export Typescript variables directly ?

Comment: I think you do some wrong while you changes the first statement to the second statement.

Comment: @trichetriche - It's just how the data is stored in the system - Business stuff above my pay grade. I had actually tried the `import * as data from '....'` before but ran into the "can't find module" problem. I will give that a try.

Comment: Well if it creates issues with your code, it's business messing with your paygrade ... But anyway, consider mocking it, since you're testing, it won't be an issue.

Comment: @trichetriche - I have updated the original question with what I'm actually doing (files included). Could you please advise? I'm probably being n00bish.

Comment: Well I wouldn't advise to use the `HttpClient` in a component, but suit yourself. Other than that, `const data = require(jsonUrl);` should be `const data = [{
    "name": "dormant",
    "id": 1,
    "validToId": [2]
  }]`. Given your test, you could even `const data = [];`, and expect a memory reference equivalency with `expect(component.raceStatuses).toBe(data)`

Comment: Ah that works great. Didn't realise you could just load basically nothing and it would word XD. What would you use instead of HttpClient, out of curiosity?

Comment: It works because `toBe` compare memory references. You could use a string, a number ... anything you want. I'm just complying with your linter by passing an array. And I don't fully understand your question, as `HttpClient` is the only module to use ? (also, @trichetriche me in your comments, otherwise I don't get notifications)

Comment: @trichetriche - I was asking about the HttpClient because you said `I wouldn't advise to use the HttpClient in a component, but suit yourself` in a previous comment.

Comment: Oh, I meant components are for handling view interactions, whereas services are used to handle business code. And making HTTP requests is business code, not view interactions. This is per Angular's style guide, it's a recommendation, not an must-do

Comment: @trichetriche - I get what you mean now. Such an action should refer to a Service of some kind rather than perform it within the component. I thought you meant I'd done something drastically wrong :P

Comment: @physicsboy kind of, considering the "action" isn't related to the view ! And no, don't worry, if you do something horribly wrong, I'll tell you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by making it equal any kind of object:

```
it('should load status data from local json', fakeAsync(() => {
    const jsonUrl = '../../../assets/greyhound.status.json';
    const data = [];

    const request = httpMock.expectOne(jsonUrl);
    request.flush(data);
    expect(component.raceStatuses).toEqual(data);
  }));
```